# Clear value into input using useState or useRef (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state, use-ref

I got **hook**:

```
const [myName, setMyName] = useState("");
const myNameRef = useRef();
```

Then I have form:

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => addVist(e, user.id)}>
 <input type="text" name="myName" ref={myNameRef} onChange={e => setMyName(e.target.value)} />
 <input type="submit" value="Run" />
</form>
```

And method:

```
const addVist = (e, userId) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(myName)
        //some code....

        //clear value form
        setMyName("");
        //setMyName('');
        //setMyName(e.target.value = "");
        //myNameRef.current.value("");

    }
```

But the `setMyName("")` is not working - still I see value inside input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed binding `myName` as `value` attribute of the `input` tag.

```
 <input type="text" name="myName" value={myName} ref={myNameRef} onChange={e => setMyName(e.target.value)} />
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a complete example of clearing `input` using state **OR** a reference:

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const inputRef = useRef();
  return (
    <>
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <input ref={inputRef} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setValue("");
          inputRef.current.value = "";
        }}
      >
        Clear
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Refer to [Controlled VS Uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components).

Comment: You actually asked how to reset with a ref as well

Comment: but if I don't need it I will not use it

Answer (score 1):

On your text input you should pass `myName` into the value attribute like so

```
<input type="text" name="myName" value={myName} ref={myNameRef} onChange={e => setMyName(e.target.value)} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add myName as value.

```
<input type="text" name="myName" value={myName} ref={myNameRef} onChange={e => setMyName(e.target.value)} />
```